# Tar extract clobbering

Tags: linux, installation, tar

I'm trying to create a simple install package that doesn't require dpkg/apt/rpm. In doing this, I've created an archive that looks a bit like this:

- /

  - etc

    - init.d

      - myservice
  - usr

    - local

      - myservice

        - somefiles

When I try and untar this across the file system with `tar -C / -xvzf archive.tar.gz`, I'm noticing that /etc/init.d is getting totally clobbered except for the files in the archive (myservice). My understanding is that this should merge the files rather than clobber. I've tried to use the `-k` flag, but this doesn't work when I need to update the files for my app. Can any of you linux geniuses assist?

Cheers,
Nick

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, /etc/init.d is actually a symlink to /etc/rc.d/init.d. So when the tar was copied over the top, it blew away the symlink and made it appear that everything was clobbered. Doh.

themoreyouknow.jpg